# How to call a method using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I got all the classes that implement my interface. I want to call a method when the instance of the object is created

```
var types =AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList()
            .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
            .Where(t => typeof(IManagerReport).IsAssignableFrom(t));

Console.WriteLine("Processing manager reports..");
foreach(var TheType in types)
{
              //error here
    var temptype = Activator.CreateInstance(TheType) as IManagerReport;

    temptype.Load();
    temptype.Save();
    Console.WriteLine("Saved to: " + temptype.SavePath);
}
```

The error that is produced is here:

> Cannot create an instance of an interface

Comment: Stuff this in on a new line between `.SelectMany` and `.Where`: `.Where(t => !t.IsInterface)` and see if that helps.

Comment: And the title is misleading, your problem has nothing to do with calling a method, it has everything to do with the fact that you're trying to construct an instance of an interface.

Comment: Sorry, If you like you can change the title. Not sure what this is called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you exclude IManagerReport from the selection of types you're fetching.

```
var types =AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList()
            .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
            .Where(t => typeof(IManagerReport).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                        && typeof(IManagerReport) != t
                        && !t.IsInterface
                        && !t.IsAbstract
                        && !t.IsGenericTypeDefinition);
```

The problem is, in your types enumerable, you've got not only the derived types of IManagerReport, but also the IManagerReport itself.  You can't create an instance of an interface, only a class.  Use the code I posted to exclude most trouble items, but I would still add a try/catch on the Activator.CreateInstance.  You may have derived types that have no parameterless public constructor.  These would also fail.

Wrap the call in a try/catch and continue.  I would say you should account for all possibilities here, but there's just simply too many of them.  Account for a few, then also account for the possibility that the creation simply won't work for another reason.

```
try {
    var temptype = Activator.CreateInstance(TheType) as IManagerReport;
} catch {
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `IManagerReport` matches your `Where` predicate and hence will be one of the values in the `foreach` statement.  You need to filter out the interfaces in the `Where` clause as well

```
var types =AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList()
            .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
            .Where(t => typeof(IManagerReport).IsAssignableFrom(t));
            .Where(t => !t.IsInterface && !t.IsAbstract);
```

Comment: Why use two where statements?  This would iterate through the enumerable, then iterate through what's left a second time.   That wouldn't be as performant as a simple && within the existing .Where statement.

Comment: @DavidMorton adding additional Where clauses is not significant performance detractor.  No more so than using an `if` in the body of the loop. It could be done as one `Where` but I find it more readable to separate the different predicates

Answer (score 1):

Try adding either

```
.Where(t=>t.IsClass)
```

or

```
.Where(t=>!t.IsInterface)
```

to your LINQ query